# Regex: match two or more of the preceding token?

Tags: regex

I am interested to see if such regex can be created? For example, this regex will match exactly two of preceding token: `^((pi|e|x|([-]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)){2})`, and I'd like to match such string as long as it has two or more of something inside.

```
//want to recognize
//piex14.3   -- will see pi, e, x, number of type double
//14e        -- will see number of type double, e
//12.5pi     -- will see number of type double, pi
//ex         -- will see e, x
```

Answer (score 5):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression:

> `{min,}`   The preceding item is matched min or more times.

You should be able to use `^((pi|e|x|([-]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)){2,})`

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it but it still can recognize `double` as only match, for example `1.6` gets matched. This is because I want to be able to recognize `.3` or `5.` as a number. So I'd need to work around that.

Comment: @Rorschach, take a look at https://ideone.com/iDIJTy. Is that not what you are trying to get?

Comment: @R Sahu. All your examples work fine, however, input line `2.4`, and you'll notice a match, even though it shouldn't be. Because of how I defined looking for a number of `double` type, but I would like to avoid changing that part.

Comment: @Rorschach, that points to the fact that you have not defined the regex correctly to meet your requirement. That's a different problem than the question you are asking -- how to specify 2 or more matches of the previous matched item.